# Selection of Items that build a text list HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out a way so that you could create an online ordering process of a pizzeria (or any restaurant), that is just the example I've picked. The idea is that when clicking on the Option selection, the item selected will fill a text value, adding to the pre-existing list all the selection from the options available.
For example, if I want both a "Viennese" and a "Norcia e Funghi", I would first select Viennese (and it would be in a text), and then select Norcia e Funghi which would be added to the text list after.

That is the best I've come up with (with the help of the Internet, of course), I am trying to improve my skills during the pandemic and I would really appreciate your help! I'm stucked!

```
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function myNewFunction(element) {
    var text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = text;
}

</script> 
</head>
<body>
<select id="box1" onChange="myNewFunction(this);">
<option value="1">Nessuna</option>
<option value="2">Viennese</option>
<option value="3">Norcia e Funghi</option>
</select>
<div id="test"></div


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to update the contents of `<div id="test"></div>` rather than replace each time an item is selected from your list.

```html
<html> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function myNewFunction(element) {
    var text = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
    //Check the items already outputted for the exact text
    //Use ... operator to convert into array
    var textItems = [...document.getElementById("test").children];
    
    //Filter through the elements to find one that includes matching text
    existingItem = textItems.filter(element => element.innerHTML.includes(text));
    
    // If there is an item with the text, then split the text by our seperator and add 1 to it before setting the inner text once more
    if (existingItem.length) {
      var itemAndQuantity = existingItem[0].innerText.split("-");
      var newQuantity = 1 + parseInt(itemAndQuantity[1]);
      existingItem[0].innerHTML = itemAndQuantity[0] + " - " + newQuantity;
    } else {
      //Create a new paragraph element, this could be a <li> instead
      var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
      //Add a - 1 for the quantity
      paragraph.innerHTML = text + " - 1";
      document.getElementById("test").appendChild(paragraph);
    }
}

</script> 
</head>
<body>
<select id="box1" onChange="myNewFunction(this);">
<option value="1">Nessuna</option>
<option value="2">Viennese</option>
<option value="3">Norcia e Funghi</option>
</select>
<div id="test"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

This will add a new Paragraph element to your div each time an item is selected from the dropdown.

Comment: YES, this is already outstanding, thank you.
What if I wanted to be able to update the list with two identical items?
I mean what if I selected "Norcia e funghi" and then again "Norcia e Funghi" because I want 2 items of this one?
ps. you've been amazing already

Comment: Updated based on what you want. Could be implemented differently, but this should give a good start.